# Is there a way to set ISO 8601 Compliant Dates as DateTime format in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I am a newbie to OreintDB and I was wondering if there is a way to get OrientDB (I am using the 3.0 Release Candidate) to accept all dates as ISO 8601 compliant dates with milliseconds. The DB I am building will store all times in UTC but needs millisecond level timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATETIMEFORMAT "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Hope it helps

Regards